# Downgrading/Partitioning Ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, partitioning, 20.04, unity, downgrade

I'm a new Ubuntu user running Ubuntu 20.04 and have been liking it so far. I have reached a dilemma now. I would like to learn Game Development via Unity Hub, a game engine requiring Ubuntu 18.04 or 16.04. I don't want to downgrade because I like this version and many other apps are 20.04 only. I want to know if I need to downgrade to 18.04, and if so, how do I partition both Ubuntu 20.04 and 18.04? I tried running Unity Hub but I can't get past the sign-in page. Thank you for your answers in advance!

Edit:
In more detail, I downloaded the Unity Hub from the Unity website for Linux (BETA), extracted the .tar file, and opened the .AppImage file to open the Unity Hub. It opens and shows a sign-in page. I hit sign-in and it opens a blank page on Chrome. For experiment, I hit create account and that signed me in on Chrome and showed my personal details, but the app did not refresh/redirect.

[Sign-in Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7zCD.jpg)
[Blank Page from Unity Hub Sign-In](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmiTr.png)

Comment: What makes you believe you need to downgrade?  What problems are you experiencing when trying to perform this task on 20.04? Describe all of the exact steps in order you are taking to reproduce the problem and describe the exact behavior that is problematic. Include all commands and error messages. "Can't get past the sign-in page" is not detailed enough. 16.04 no longer receives community support and 18.04 won't be supported forever so I'm sure there's a way to perform your task on 20.04 but we need more details about the problem to help you solve that problem

Comment: @Nmath In this case the information provided in the question was sufficient for me to post an answer, but as usual in Linux there is probably more than one method and some methods require more details than others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### How to install Unity Game Engine in Ubuntu 20.04

In order to install Unity Hub in Ubuntu 20.04 you need to download the older Unity Hub AppImage file which unlike the newer Unity Hub .tar.gz file can also be installed in Ubuntu 20.04.

Download Unity Hub for Linux from [here](https://public-cdn.cloud.unity3d.com/hub/prod/UnityHub.AppImage).  Select the *Save File* option and press *OK*. The UnityHub.AppImage file will be downloaded in the Downloads directory.  Every AppImage contains an app and all the files the app needs to run. For this reason the UnityHub.AppImage file can be installed in Ubuntu 20.04 despite the different system requirements (Ubuntu 16.04 or Ubuntu 18.04) of the newer Unity Hub .tar.gz file.

[image]

Once the file is downloaded, open the terminal, change directories to the `~/Downloads/` directory, make the AppImage file executable, and run the executable AppImage file.

```
cd ~/Downloads  
chmod a+x UnityHub.AppImage
./UnityHub.AppImage
```

Read the Unity Terms of Service and agree to them.

[image]

The following message will be printed in the terminal after accepting the license.

```
License accepted
Checking for update
Generated new staging user ID: f97abfd4-1de8-a7e2-53b5-206e7050b831
Update for version 2.4.5 is not available (latest version: 2.4.5, downgrade is disallowed).
Checking for update
Found version 3.0.0-beta.6 (url: UnityHubBeta.AppImage)
```

Unlike version 2.4.5 UnityHub version 3.0.0 is a beta version.

If you are running Unity Hub for the first time, click *Manage License* in the bottom right corner and log into the Unity Hub through Google, Facebook, or Single.

[image]

Click *Preferences* and select the *Installs* option.

[image]

Add the Unity version by selecting the *Add* button.

[image]

Add modules to your install and click *Done*.

[image]

The selected Unity version and modules will install.

[image]

When the Unity version and modules install, click the *Projects* tab, and create a new project.

[image]

The Unity project will open, and you can start creating games using Unity immediately.

<sub>**source:** revised from [How to Install Unity 2020.2.1f1 in Ubuntu 20.04](https://linuxhint.com/install-unity-2020-2-1f1-ubuntu-20-04/)</sub>

Comment: I get an error after downloading and trying to open saying: "Could Not Display "UnityHubBeta.AppImage"

Comment: I changed the download link in the second paragraph of my answer. This one works.

Comment: Thank you, I think both links work, I had uninstalled firefox and also forgotten the terminal steps.